# Condition in v-for of vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I would like to avoid `image` value in below code.`image` is a key for `property`. How can I do that ?

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="obj in data" :id="obj.id">
       <td v-for="property in obj">{{property}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. What are you trying to do? Not make a `td` for any object that has an image?

Comment: Thanks @HEATH3N for your reply. There are different values in `{{property}}`. But I would not like to print value of `image` property.

Comment: So is `property` an object? Because the way you're calling `property.image` suggests that it is.

Comment: No, `property` is a value. I am updating my question. I don't know how to do that's why I  was calling `property.image`. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-essential.html#avoid-v-if-with-v-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let check it out: [`v-for` with an Object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object), [`v-for` with `v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if).

```
<td v-for="(value, property) in obj" v-if="property!='image'">
    {{value}}
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben for your reply. I tried like this `<td v-for="property in obj" v-if="!property.image">{{property}}</td>`. But it is not working. Thanks

Comment: also check for https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: I guess you should try `<td v-for="(value, property) in obj" v-if="property!='image'">{{value}}</td>`

Comment: ^ That works and is much better than my mess of an answer.

Comment: Note that it’s not recommended to use v-if and v-for together. Refer to style guide for details. (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if)

Comment: I.e. "When they exist on the same node, v-if has a higher priority than v-for. That means the v-if condition will not have access to variables from the scope of the v-for" -- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-v-if

Answer (score 17):

The Accepted answer is an anti-pattern because you should not mix `v-for` and `v-if` on the same node in VueJs 2+ as Thomas van Broekhoven pointed out. Instead, you can just chain a filter onto the object.  Here is an example using an ES6 arrow function which *should** work.

- Untested syntax. Typing on my phone, in bed.

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="obj in data" :id="obj.id">
       <td v-for="property in obj.filter(property => property !== 'image')">{{property}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: eslint-plugin-vue errors tho, says `'v-for' directives require that attribute value.`